# ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 - Removing UserKestrel() for deployment to Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

What is the correct way to add optional methods to BuildWebHost() in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0?

I need to add UseKestrel() in my development environment to enable HTTPS locally, but I need to remove that in production because Azure Websites does not like it.

Background:

I migrated an ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 app to 2.0.  In particular, I followed the steps outlined here regarding the Program.cs changes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#update-main-method-in-programcs

That document outlines the new pattern required to construct the web host ... based on that, here's the new 2.0 version of my BuildWebHost() method that works on development:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
      {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("mycert.pfx", "password");
      });
    })
    .Build();
```

After deploying to Azure, I got a 502.5 error, and looking at the event logs in Kudu I found this:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/BEASTMUFFIN' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\BeastMuffin.Web.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352.
```

Searching for and reading about that specific error code, I realized this is probably related to my Program.cs, and was already concerned about the UseKestrel() method call.

I commented out that line and re-published and it worked perfectly.

So, back to the original question ... how can I follow the new pattern for constructing the web host but when running locally, include the UseKestrel() method and its options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off I would like to say I am a huge fan of yours.  Cut my teeth at LearnVisualStudio.net many, many, years ago, even convinced my employer (at the time) to buy me a lifetime membership.  Thank you sir!

**Option #1:** I have seen Shawn Wildermuth use this code (***#if DEBUG***) in a couple of different Pluralsight videos, and suspect it might work for your purposes.

```js
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
#if DEBUG    
    .UseKestrel(options =>H
    {
      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
      {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("mycert.pfx", "password");
      });
    })
#endif    
    .Build();
```

**Option #2:** Add the **IHostingEnvironment** to the Program Main method signature and call a different HostBuild method depending on the environment variable.

```js
        public static void Main(string[] args, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
            {
                BuildLocalWebHost(args).Run();
            }
            else
            {
                BuildAzureWebHost(args).Run();
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps or at least points in the right direction.

Comment: A doubly-good answer.  :)  First, thanks for the #if DEBUG tip.  I've heard Shawn does an amazing job.  I'm only reluctant to watch anyone else's content in fear of plagiarism accusations.  Also, I didn't realize you could use it in the middle of a chain of method calls like that!  Second, thanks for the personal note.  I'm glad to be a small part of so many people's learning experience.  Best wishes to you!

Comment: Actually, I tried the latter solution first because it feels right ... but, hows does IHostingEnvironment get it passed in?  In my case, I'm getting an error message when I attempt to run this: "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Comment: Also, one more thing ... from experimentation, the name of the method MUST be: BuildWebHost() ... otherwise the EF Core 2 tooling will not work.  In my opinion, this was not emphasized sufficiently in the documentation.